# Three.js spotlights not casting shadow

Tags: three.js

See http://www.xpos.nl/clock/ for problem at hand.

The page also has links to video's of an animation and real clock of what I'm trying to achive with three.js.

It's a clock with 2 leds rotating around a pin in the center. The shadows make the hands of the clock.

I'm a complete novice when it comes to three.js/webgl, but with some help of 'experts' on three.js I/we got this far:
http://www.xpos.nl/clock/
(the clock ticks with one minute per second to speed up the animation)

The one thing is missing: the hands of the clock. The center pin does not show the shadows the spotlights should cast.

Why does the center pin does not have any shadows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cast shadows in three.js, you must add:

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

light.castShadow = true;
```

three.js r.73

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm creating a light that moves with an object, but the light doesn't cast shadows on any objects.

Comment: This is a really poor answer. Makes no attempt to explain the how, why, order or reason.